# How to access class properties through an Interface instance using Unity.WebApi

Tags: c#, oop, asp.net-web-api, interface, inversion-of-control

Is it possible to expose class public properties in different class through IOC. I am creating an instance of Interface but i am not able to access public properties of class. I am using Unity.WebApi for resolving dependencies.

**TransactionService Class**

```
public class TransactionService : ITransactionService
{
    private readonly IMRepository _mRepository;
    private readonly IFService _fGateway;

     public TransactionService(IMbaRepository mbaRepository, IFpnService fpnService)
    {
        _mRepository = mRepository;
        _fGateway = fService;
    }

     private List<Transaction> SearchTransacionsByUser(FUser objFUser)
    {

         foreach (var item in something)
         {
              //can't use _fGateway to set properties because Interface 
              //  don't implement them
              _fGateway.OID = objFUser.OID.ToString();
             _fGateway.Amount = objFUser.Amount;

             _fGateway.Search(criteria);

         }

    }



}
```

**FService class**

```
public class FService : IFpService
{

  public string _OID { get; set; }
  public decimal _Amount{ get; set; }

  public TransactionResponse Search(string criteria)
  {

         TransactionOperationInput _input;
            _input = new TransactionOperationInput()
            {
                Criteria = _criteria,
                OID = _OID,
                Amount = _Amount
            };

           // search transactions
     }



 }
```

Comment: Are you able to update interface to include missing property? This looks like a design issue.

Comment: Otherwise you would need to cast the interface. This however is a bad design as it tightly couples to implementation concerns which goes against the very reason for injecting abstractions..

Comment: I don't have any control over _input = new TransactionOperationInput() bcause its part of dll file.

Comment: I was referring to `IFService` interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in control of the services then refactor the interfaces to expose the desired members

```
public interface IFService {
   TransactionResponse Search(TransactionOperationInput input);
}
```

Make sure the derived implementation has those members

```
public class FService : IFpService {

    public TransactionResponse Search(TransactionOperationInput input) { 

           // search transactions
    }
}
```

And that the dependent class uses the correct abstraction

```
public class TransactionService : ITransactionService {
    private readonly IMRepository _mRepository;
    private readonly IFService fGateway;

    public TransactionService(IMbaRepository mbaRepository, IFService fService) {
        _mRepository = mRepository;
        fGateway = fService;
    }

    private List<Transaction> SearchTransacionsByUser(FUser objFUser) {    
        foreach (var item in something) {

            TransactionOperationInput input = new TransactionOperationInput() {
                Criteria = _criteria,
                OID =  objFUser.OID.ToString(),
                Amount = objFUser.Amount,
            };

             fGateway.Search(input);

            //...
         }

        //...
    }
}
```

Finally make sure the register the appropriate abstractions and implementations with the IoC/DI container.

Comment: can IFService expose an object of TransactionOperationInput class which is in dll? I was thinking about having  TransactionOperationInput object in TransactionService class where i can set all inputs and then pass it as argument to search method in Fservice.

Comment: @user1263981 yes you can do that. That is a more solid design as well.

Comment: @user1263981 check updated answer based on your comment

Comment: @user1263981 also if you find the answers useful remember to vote them up as well.

Comment: Thanks. Search(TransactionOperationInput input) is a private method in TransactionService. TransanctionService implements two methods and it also has one private method which is being called in implemented method with in the class.